# WD Blue Hard Drive - BIOS Shows 0

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios

I recently replaced the HDD in my Samsung RV411 and upgraded it to 500 GB. After a few days, it gave me the message "No System Found." When I looked in the BIOS, it shows the HDD, but the size is 0 Bytes. I tried to take the HDD out and re-install it a few times, but I still get the same message. I installed the old drive and everything is fine in BIOS.

When I put the new one back, it started working fine, but the next day I had the same problem. I left the computer alone for a day and it worked fine after that. It seems like every other day I will get an error.

Is there something wrong with my HDD? Is there anything else that I can try to fix this issue?

Comment: Will your computer boot the OS? If so, what OS? You could run a few programs against the HDD to see if it reports any errors. Also, is this a new HDD, one that you might be able to exchange for a working one or at least submit it for warranty purposes?

Comment: Sounds like a bad drive.  Test it in another computer and/or RMA it ( they will probably ask you to run their diagnostic software first ).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to plug the drive in a different port of the motherboard and on different computer to see if the WD Blue will be recognized.

If it doesn't, you can run a test on the drive using WD Data Lifeguard Diagnostics to see if the program will detect any errors or bad sectors on the HDD. You can download it from here:

http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=gn2GPr

Let me know how it went. :)